# GNUPlot Canvas throwing error for hypertext command

Tags: gnuplot

Code:

```
set bar 1.000000 front
set style circle radius graph 0.02, first 0.00000, 0.00000 
set style ellipse size graph 0.05, 0.03, first 0.00000 angle 0 units xy
unset key
set encoding utf8
set datafile separator "    "
set term canvas
set style data lines
set title "Scattered Graph"
set xlabel "GM %"
set terminal canvas solid butt size 1800,1000 enhanced mousing fsize 10 lw 1 fontscale 1 name 'canvas_1' jsdir '/tmp/'
set ylabel "Conversion Rate"
set grid
set timestamp
save_encoding = "utf8"
plot '/tmp/scat.dat' using 2:3:1 with labels hypertext point pt 7 ps var lc rgb "#ffee99"
quit
```

There are three columns in scat.dat like name  x y where x and y are values in scattered plot and name is the hyperlink.

But when i try to run this file its throwing error as below:

```
plot '/tmp/scat.dat' using 2:3:1 with labels hypertext point pt 7 ps var lc rgb "#ffee99"
                                             ^
"/tmp/scat.cmd", line 16: ';' expected
```

I can't figure it out what is the missing thing. GNUPLOT Ver. 4.6

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with Gnuplot 4.6. The hypertext feature was introduced with Gnuplot 5, see [release notes](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/ReleaseNotes_5_0_5.html).